# All tickvalues not getting displayed on X axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am making a stacked multi chart bar graph like this one

http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html

Till now I am able to push my values on Y- axis and X axis too but the problem I am facing is that the all the values are not getting displayed on the x axis but only 10 values are getting displayed . I am using nvD3 library in my angular code . and displaying date on x axis.

[image: Dates coming with a gap of 3 days]

```
  $scope.options1 = {
    chart: {
      type: 'multiBarChart',
      height: 600,
      margin: {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 200,
    left: 45
      },
      clipEdge: false,
      duration: 500,
      stacked: true,
      groupSpacing: 0.1,
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      showMaxMin: false,
      xAxis: {
    axisLabel: 'Timeline',
    showMaxMin: false,
    tickFormat: function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%d-%m-%y')(new Date(d))
    },
    xScale:d3.time.scale(),
    rotateLabels: '-70'
      },
      yAxis: {
    axisLabel: 'Pending Bills',
    axisLabelDistance: -20,
    groupSpacing: 0.1,
    tickFormat: function(d) {
      return d3.format(',f')(d);
    }
      }
    }
  };
```

generating ticking value array using this function

```
$scope.options1.chart.xAxis.tickValues = function() {
      var xTick = _.map(data.data.data[0].values, function(value) {
    return value.x;
      });
      xTick = _.sortBy(xTick, function(date){ return new Date(date); });
      console.log(xTick);
      return xTick;
    }
```

the output of the console.log(xTick) is something like this which is all dates -

> ["2015-09-01", "2015-09-02", "2015-09-03", "2015-09-04", "2015-09-05",
>   "2015-09-06", "2015-09-07", "2015-09-08", "2015-09-09", "2015-09-10",
>   "2015-09-11", "2015-09-12", "2015-09-13", "2015-09-14", "2015-09-15",
>   "2015-09-16", "2015-09-17", "2015-09-18", "2015-09-19", "2015-09-20",
>   "2015-09-21", "2015-09-22", "2015-09-23", "2015-09-24", "2015-09-25",
>   "2015-09-26", "2015-09-27", "2015-09-28", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-30",
>   "2015-10-01", "2015-10-02", "2015-10-03", "2015-10-04", "2015-10-05",
>   "2015-10-06", "2015-10-07", "2015-10-08", "2015-10-09", "2015-10-10",
>   "2015-10-11", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-13", "2015-10-14", "2015-10-15",
>   "2015-10-16", "2015-10-17", "2015-10-18", "2015-10-19", "2015-10-20"]

as much I read about the it. all the dates should be get plotted on x axis but  they are  not

Comment: can you put this up on a working fiddle?

Comment: OK I am doing it right away .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all the ticks on X-Axis, you can add this option to your chart options :

```
"reduceXTicks": false,
```

For extended option page you can visit :

[Angular NVD3 - MultiBarChart](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks For the help . It really worked . thanks once again .

Answer (score 0):

```
chart: {
    type: 'chartType',
    xAxis: {
        ticks:8
    }
}
```

You can try "ticks" property if you want to display a specific number of ticks on the axis.